# Line numbers of search string in a file

Tags: matlab, text-processing, findstr

How i can find the line number of the searched string in a file in Matlab?

example:

f=fileread(file name);

LineNum=strfind(f,word);

the previous didn't give me the correct line.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach that uses **[`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)** -

```
f=importdata(filename1) %// filename1 is the path to your file
LineNum= find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(f,word)))
```

Comment: @alsadi90 Awesome! :)